# Using Azure Resource Group Tags in a Azure Logic Apps Workflow

Tags: tags, workflow, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-group

I have a question about the Resource Group Tags in Azure, is it possible to fetch the tag name/values and use them in an logic app workflow?
As in for example use the tag names/values in the body of a mail-action to send to a recipient?

Is it possible to use the Graph API for example to get these tags into the logic app workflow?

**UPDATE:**

This is how i tried to call the endpoint to get the tags.

[image]

This doesn't work because after a while the token will expire.

then i tried doing it this way:

[image]

This doesn't work either because for some reason when i register the LA in my AD i and later on input the relevant information it just denies my access.

BTW the information displayed in those pictures is only for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD Graph API doesn't provide the feature to return Resource Groups Tags information .

You can use the Resource Management API :

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups?api-version=2017-05-10
```

It will return tags attached to the resource group. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/ResourceGroups/List) .

Comment: Yes, i was testing that the other day. The thing is that i need a bearer token, for that i think i need to register the logic app in my azure ad. I tried it but bith no success. Gettin the token that is.

Comment: Please refer to [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect) for how to call web API in a web app using Azure AD and OpenID Connect.

Comment: I don't do this by code, i do this by logic app workflow. But i have updated the information with the relevant snippets of what i am doing in my logic app.